# What is the best way for a node app to maintain connection with hundred or even thousands of databases using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a multi-tenant Saas App. I was advised by many to keep my separate clients on separate databases, for better security and easier management.

How do we connect multiple databases to the Node app?

I know how to make my app run with a single database connection to mongodb, but not sure about multiple connections.

The mongoose docs mentions the following solutions for multiple connections:

1. export schema pattern (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections)
2. connection pools (which has only up to 5 connections, which may not be ideal as I may have hundreds of clients in the future)

Another way which I tried (and it works!), is connecting to mongodb during a node API call and executing my logic, as shown below. The code below is a test route for registering a user with name and email. dbutils() is a function that I call to connect to mongodb, using mongoose.connect(). I am not sure if this is a good practice to connect during the API call.

```
router.post('/:db/register', async (req,res, next) => {
  const startTime = new Date();


  try {
    if(!req.body.name) {
      throw new Error("Name required");
    }

    if(!req.body.email) {
      throw new Error("Email required");
    }

    await dbutils(req.params.db);// connect to db

    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();


    const newUser = new User({
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
    })

    await newUser.save({session});

    await session.commitTransaction();
    session.endSession();

    const endTime = new Date();

    const diff = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();

    return res.json({
      newUser: {
        email: req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name
      },
      db: req.params.db,
      timeElapsed: diff,
    });


  } catch(ex) {
    return next(ex);
  }



})
```

My dbutils() code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const mongoURI = "mongodb://PC:27017,PC:27018,PC:27019";

module.exports = async function(db) {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(
      `${mongoURI}/${db}`,
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      }
    )
  } catch(ex) {
    throw ex
  }

}
```

I would be very happy for any recommendation or solution to this problem. Thank you very much in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to connect to your `DB` in an API call, you will be wasting a lot of resources, and deplaying the `API` responses as well.

The best way for you would be connect to `multiple databases` when Application starts, along with `connection pooling` configuration.

You can specify which schema belongs to which `connection`, and maintain separate `DB` collections.

**You can use below code to work with multiple connections, and pooling:**

```
const connection1 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://username:password@host1:port1[?options]',{
    poolSize: 10
});

const connection2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://username:password@host2:port2[?options]',{
    poolSize: 10
});
```

**Models/Schema on connection 1 can be created as below:**

```
//User schema on connection 1
const userSchema = new Schema({ ... });
const UserModel = connection1.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = UserModel;
```

**Models/Schema on connection 2 can be created as below:**

```
//Product schema on connection 2
const productSchema = new Schema({ ... });
const ProductModel = connection2.model('Product', productSchema);

module.exports = ProductModel;
```

For better performance, you can also have shared DB clusters for each DB, and use the cluster to connect to your database.

```
const conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]', options);
```

For detailed information, Please read [Mongoose Multiple Connections](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#mongos_connections), and [Connection Pooling](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection_pools)